# How to perform String Operations in ios?

Tags: ios, string

I have n number of files.I appended that n number of files to table view.Actually that n number of files are of one folder.But when i append those files to table view they are appended to table view with in  a single row seperated by comma.How to split them into different rows in table view.Please give me suggestions and please help me out.

Comment: Without seeing your existing code, it's very difficult to offer any guidance.

Comment: thanks for responding i will show my code

Comment: "0.rtf",
   "1.pdf.rtf",
   "2.rtf",
   "3.rtf",
   "4.rtf",
   "5.rtf",
   "6.rtf",
   "7.rtf",
   "8.rtf",
   "9.rtf",
   "Untitled.pdf" i have my string like this.All the strings are appended in a single row in a table view.How to show one of them in each one cell

Comment: Actually how you are getting the filenames? Can you pl. show ur code?

Comment: ilemanager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
   filelist=[filemanager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users/user/Desktop/ratnakar" error:NULL];
   count=[filelist count];
   NSLog(@"the count of the files in the mac OSX are::%d",count);
   for(i=0;i<count;i++)
       {
       NSLog(@"*****************%@******************",[filelist objectAtIndex:i]);        
       }

Comment: list=[[NSArray alloc]init];
       //list=[result copy];
        list=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:result, nil];
   self.tableViewArray=list;

Comment: NSString *result=[filelist description];
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleTableIdentifier"];
   
   if(cell==nil)
       {
       cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableIdentifier"]autorelease];
       
       }
   
   cell.textLabel.text=[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   return cell

Comment: Am getting the output as  "0.rtf",
   "1.pdf.rtf",
   "2.rtf",
   "3.rtf",
   "4.rtf",
   "5.rtf",
   "6.rtf",
   "7.rtf",
   "8.rtf",
   "9.rtf",
   "Untitled.pdf"

Comment: here filelist is NSArray

Comment: @DurgaPrasad: Don't put code in comments. Amend your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [componentsSeparatedByString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have the file names in an array, say `fileNames`, which are found in `viewDidLoad` method.

And implement the methods as following:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [fileNames count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [fileNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yeah.i did but when i appended that array variable to cell,it displayed all the data in a single row seperated by a comma

Answer (score 0):

Store your list of files in an array with one file name per array element and use `indexPath.row` to choose the right one.

Use `componentsSeparatedByString:` if you need to break up the single string.